# Exchanging unique strings to integers

Tags: php

Ok, so the issue I am having is I am returning the count of the number of l's and d's from a database as a string, but I need it to be an integer. I tried to cast it as an int after but when i do it just returns each number as 0. I know it is returning a string, and when I echo $count1 (which is the string) it returns the actual number just find, but when I cast it, it doesn't work.

By the way there is a ton of entries and each one is unique, so the basic rundown is like

12
10
9
when I return it as a string but when I return it as an int it is

0
0
0

```
$db_name = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_host = '';
try{
// database connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$db_user,$db_pass);
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
}
$table = 'ratings';
$con = 'data';
$id = (empty($_GET['id'])) ? : $_GET['id'] ;

$sql5 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM $table WHERE id='$id' AND rating = 'l'");
$sql5->execute();
$count = $sql5->fetchColumn();

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM $table WHERE id='$id' AND rating = 'd'");
$sql->execute();
$count1 = $sql->fetchColumn();
$plsWerk = (int)$count1;
var_dump($plsWerk);
var_dump($count1);


$qq = "SELECT * FROM $con";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($qq);
$stmt1->execute();
$rr = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
echo $count1;
```

I am not currently echoing plswerk but that is what I want to replace count1.
Thanks!

Comment: At what place exactly does the conversion fail? What is the type before and what is the type after that? Use `var_dump()` to find out and remove all other code that is irrelevant, like e.g. the whole database stuff.

Comment: First of all, you should not make in individual SQL query for each value that you need a count for, but do that all in one query and use GROUP BY. // What is the _exact_ `var_dump` output you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$foo = intval('33');` rather than `$foo = (int)('33');`

So:

```
$plsWerk = intval($count1);
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I use invtal for 2 reasons. Firstly because I simply prefer how it looks as its easier to read  especially when your're working with more complicated expressions you can just wrap the whole thing in an intval(). This for me makes up for the fact that people say its slower. And secondly, you can specify a base so you can cast hexadecimal (or other base) numbers to integers easily. eg: $foo = (intval('FF', 16)); will be 255